# Can I enable just Spring Session header authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

For the time being I see no reason to add Redis but all Spring Session examples include it. I want to design with the idea in mind that I might add it later. The thing I want right now is Header Authentication.

How can I enable the Header Authentication without enabling Redis?

(a spring boot single file application as example would be nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with version 1.2 and untested, 1.1

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MapSessionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-mapsessionrepository) was created for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a filter of type        -       `SessionRepositoryFilter<Session>`, which in a Spring Boot application means a `@Bean` of that type. When you create it you just inject a `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`.